# Multiple Joins 6 itens

Tags: sql, join

I'm dealing with multiple joins... And I'm not able to do the joins.

Here comes the problem

Tables

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `catleathers` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `code` varchar(55) NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(55) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `id` (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=21 ;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `catsoles` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `code` varchar(55) NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(55) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `id` (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=16 ;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `products` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `code` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `name` char(255) NOT NULL,
  `unit` varchar(255) DEFAULT '1',
  `size` varchar(255) DEFAULT '1',
  `cost` decimal(25,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `price` decimal(25,2) NOT NULL,
  `alert_quantity` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '20',
  `image` varchar(255) DEFAULT 'no_image.jpg',
  `category_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `subcategory_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `catleather_id_a` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `subcatleather_id_a` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `catleather_id_b` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `subcatleather_id_b` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `catleather_id_c` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `subcatleather_id_c` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `catsole_id_a` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `subcatsole_id_a` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `catsole_id_b` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `subcatsole_id_b` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `catsole_id_c` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `subcatsole_id_c` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `sortido` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `lining` varchar(150) NOT NULL,
  `lining_description` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `sole_a` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `sole_b` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `sole_a_description` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `sole_b_description` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `leather_a` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `leather_b` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `leather_c` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `leather_a_description` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `leather_b_description` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `leather_c_description` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `carts` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `quantity` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `tax_rate` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `track_quantity` tinyint(4) DEFAULT '1',
  `details` varchar(1000) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `code` (`code`),
  KEY `category_id` (`category_id`),
  KEY `id` (`id`),
  KEY `id_2` (`id`),
  KEY `category_id_2` (`category_id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=79
```

How can I do this multiple joins?

```
        ->join('categories', 'products.category_id=categories.id', 'left')
        ->join('subcategories', 'products.subcategory_id=subcategories.id', 'left')


        ->join('catleathers', 'products.catleather_id_a=catleathers.id', 'left')
        ->join('subcatleathers', 'products.subcatleather_id_a=subcatleathers.id', 'left')

        ->join('catleathers', 'products.catleather_id_b=catleathers.id', 'left')
        ->join('subcatleathers', 'products.subcatleather_id_b=subcatleathers.id', 'left')

        ->join('catleathers', 'products.catleather_id_c=catleathers.id', 'left')
        ->join('subcatleathers', 'products.subcatleather_id_c=subcatleathers.id', 'left')

        ->join('catsoles', 'products.catsole_id_a=catsoles.id', 'left')
        ->join('subcatsoles', 'products.subcatsole_id_a=subcatsoles.id', 'left')

        ->join('catsoles', 'products.catsole_id_b=catsoles.id', 'left')
        ->join('subcatsoles', 'products.subcatsole_id_b=subcatsoles.id', 'left')

        ->join('catsoles', 'products.catsole_id_c=catsoles.id', 'left')
        ->join('subcatsoles', 'products.subcatsole_id_c=subcatsoles.id', 'left')

        ->join('tbl_lining', 'products.lining=tbl_lining.id', 'left')

        ->group_by("products.id");
```

Someone can give me a hand with this multiples joins?

Comment: Can you provide a schema (table definitions) and an example of the output you are looking to get?

Comment: When I say table definition, I mean something like this... http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_create_table.asp. The thing in your question is a list of columns that defines a result set, not a table.

Comment: Thank you

Here it goes 

I need to display the data in a table
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/eac021

Comment: You have one table, so there is nothing to join. Are there other tables that you seed to get data from?

Comment: They are in this folder https://www.dropbox.com/sh/hz6qxjmyug73c9q/AACPII7fFC5vKSHAsohXpsxza?dl=0

Thank you

Comment: I'm kind a newbie in sql statments.. So I've tried with multiple selects but if you can give me a hand I'll will try to do it with joins

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should be what you need, notice for the "A", "B" and "C" instances, I am grabbing the alias.Column AS FinalColumnName for the query.

```
SELECT  
      p.id,
      p.name,
      p.code,
      clA.code as claCode,
      sclA.code as sclaCode,
      clB.code as clbCode,
      sclB.code as sclbCode,
      clC.code as clcCode,
      sclC.code as sclcCode
   FROM 
      products p
         INNER JOIN catleathers clA
            ON p.catleather_id_a = clA.id
         INNER JOIN subcatleathers sclA
            ON p.subcatleather_id_a = sclA.id
         INNER JOIN catleathers clB
            ON p.catleather_id_b = clB.id
         INNER JOIN subcatleathers sclB
            ON p.subcatleather_id_b = sclB.id
         INNER JOIN catleathers clC
            ON p.catleather_id_c = clC.id
         INNER JOIN subcatleathers sclC
           ON p.subcatleather_id_c = sclC.id
```

However, I have also seen that some engines do not like the "AS" clause, so the columns in question might need to be adjusted to

```
      clA.code   claCode,
      sclA.code  sclaCode,
      clB.code   clbCode,
      sclB.code  sclbCode,
      clC.code   clcCode,
      sclC.code  sclcCode
```

Answer (score 0):

I took the liberty of adding the table schemas to your question, and I think I understand what you are looking for. I think this should be enough of a starting point that you can fill in the remaining tables.

```
SELECT
  p.id
  , p.name
  , p.code
  , 'claCode' = clA.code
  , 'claName' = clA.name
  , 'clbCode' = clB.code
  , 'clbName' = clB.name
FROM Products p
  INNER JOIN catleathers clA
     ON p.catleather_id_a = clA.id
  INNER JOIN catleathers clB
     ON p.catleather_id_b = clB.id
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved by DRapp

```
    SELECT  
      p.id,
      p.name,
      p.code,
      clA.code as claCode,
      sclA.code as sclaCode,
      clB.code as clbCode,
      sclB.code as sclbCode,
      clC.code as clcCode,
      sclC.code as sclcCode,

    catSoleA.code as catSoleACode,
    subcatSoleA.code as subcatSoleACode,

    catSoleB.code as catSoleBCode,
    subcatSoleB.code as subcatSoleBCode,

    catSoleC.code as catSoleCCode,
    subcatSoleC.code as subcatSoleCCode

   FROM 
      products p
         INNER JOIN catleathers clA
            ON p.catleather_id_a = clA.id
         INNER JOIN subcatleathers sclA
            ON p.subcatleather_id_a = sclA.id
         INNER JOIN catleathers clB
            ON p.catleather_id_b = clB.id
         INNER JOIN subcatleathers sclB
            ON p.subcatleather_id_b = sclB.id
         INNER JOIN catleathers clC
            ON p.catleather_id_c = clC.id
         INNER JOIN subcatleathers sclC
           ON p.subcatleather_id_c = sclC.id

        INNER JOIN catsoles catSoleA
            ON p.catsole_id_a = catSoleA.id
         INNER JOIN subcatsoles subcatSoleA
           ON p.subcatsole_id_a = subcatSoleA.id

        INNER JOIN catsoles catSoleB
            ON p.catsole_id_b = catSoleB.id
         INNER JOIN subcatsoles subcatSoleB
           ON p.subcatsole_id_b = subcatSoleB.id

        INNER JOIN catsoles catSoleC
            ON p.catsole_id_c = catSoleC.id
         INNER JOIN subcatsoles subcatSoleC
           ON p.subcatsole_id_c = subcatSoleC.id
```

It works on sql query, but isn't working on php coding

```
->select("
                products.id as productid, 
                products.image as image, 
                products.code as code, 
                pproducts.name as name, 

                categories.name as cname, 
                subcategories.name as subcategory, 
                products.cost, 
                products.price,   


                clA.code as claCode,
                sclA.code as sclaCode,
                clB.code as clbCode,
                sclB.code as sclbCode,
                clC.code as clcCode,
                sclC.code as sclcCode,

                catSoleA.code as catSoleACode,
                subcatSoleA.code as subcatSoleACode,

                catSoleB.code as catSoleBCode,
                subcatSoleB.code as subcatSoleBCode,

                catSoleC.code as catSoleCCode,
                subcatSoleC.code as subcatSoleCCode




            products.details", FALSE)

            ->from('products')


            ->join('catleathers clA', 'products.catleather_id_a = clA.id', 'INNER')
            ->join('subcatleathers sclA', 'products.subcatleather_id_a = sclA.id', 'INNER')

            ->join('catleathers clB', 'products.catleather_id_a = clB.id', 'INNER')
            ->join('subcatleathers sclB', 'products.subcatleather_id_a = sclB.id', 'INNER')

            ->join('catleathers clC', 'products.catleather_id_a = clC.id', 'INNER')
            ->join('subcatleathers sclC', 'products.subcatleather_id_a = sclC.id', 'INNER')

            ->join('catsoles catSoleA', 'products.catsole_id_a = catSoleA.id', 'INNER')
            ->join('subcatsoles subcatSoleA', 'products.subcatsole_id_a = subcatSoleA.id', 'INNER')

            ->join('catsoles catSoleB', 'products.catsole_id_b = catSoleB.id', 'INNER')
            ->join('subcatsoles subcatSoleB', 'products.subcatsole_id_b = subcatSoleB.id', 'INNER')

            ->join('catsoles catSoleC', 'products.catsole_id_c = catSoleC.id', 'INNER')
            ->join('subcatsoles subcatSoleC', 'products.subcatsole_id_c = subcatSoleC.id', 'INNER')




            ->join('tbl_lining', 'products.lining=tbl_lining.id', 'left')






            ->group_by("products.id");
```

What I'm doing wrong?